# How to get a value which is a list from redis key-value store in golang?

Tags: go, redis, key-value

I am writing a function in golang to get the value from redis db by passing the key. The value is a list. I am using 'GET' redis command to get the value. But it is giving me error.

You can find below the code,

```
func GetValue(key string) []string {
    var value []string
    var err error
    value, err = redis.Strings(conn.Do("GET", key))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
    return value
}

func RetrieveValue() {
    keyType, _ := conn.Do("TYPE", recentItemKey)
    fmt.Println("Type", keyType)

    var results []string
    results = GetValue(recentItemKey)

    for _, val := range results {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

And the output is here,

```
Type list
2015/03/14 19:09:12 WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
exit status 1
```

**Version**

```
Go 1.4.2
Redis-2.8.19
```

**Redis Go Library**

```
github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis
```

Could anyone help me on this.? Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) to get the elements of a list:

```
func GetValues(key string) []string {
  value, err := redis.Strings(conn.Do("LRANGE", key, 0, -1))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  return value
}
```

The GET command gets the value of a string key. The GET command does not work on list keys.

Comment: Could you please explain why we use the range as 0, -1? And Is there any place where I can refer go examples for REDIS commands?

Comment: http://redis.io/commands - in this case, `0` is the start of the list and `-1` represents the last element of the list. The `-1` idiom is common amongst programming languages to represent the same thing.